# How to access an array from main() with a member function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, compiler-errors

I have this subclass Pirate.cpp and I want its `mov` function to access an array from main.
This array is basically the map (To check if it already has ship, dock and to access the array to change the object's (pirate ship) location from `map[1][1]` to `map[1][2]`.

This map is a two-dimensional array of sea objects that each one can hold a ship with the pointer.

Ship is parent class of pirate (I have other subclasses I will do `dynamic_cast` before inserting `Pirate` to the `Ship` pointer).

I have an error code: `'Map' , 'Place' was not declared in this scope` which I understand.

So basically how do I deal with this scope issue? Is there an alternate approach?

Pirate.cpp

```
#include "pirate.h"
#include "Sea.h"

void Pirate::mov()
{
    MAP[1][2]->(*place)=MAP[1][1]->(*place)
    MAP[1][2]->(*place)=NULL
}
```

Sea.h

```
#ifndef SEA.H
#define SEA.H
#include "ship.h"

class Sea
{
private:
    bool hasShip;
    bool isDock;
protected:
    Ship *place = NULL;
public:
    bool gethasShip() const {return hasShip;}
    bool getisDock() const  {return isDock;}
    void sethasShip(bool i) {hasShip = i;}
    void setisDock(bool i)  {isDock = i;}
};
#endif
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "Sea.h"
#define SIZE 100

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

extern Sea Map[SIZE][SIZE];
int main()
{
    Sea Map[SIZE][SIZE];
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to get rif of variable `bool Sea::hasShip` & `void Sea::sethasShip(bool)` - you have no `Ship` when `place` is `NULL`, doesn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` makes a declaration instead of a definition. It only says that somewhere the object is definied.

You need to have `Sea Map[SIZE][SIZE];` in your main.cpp and `extern Sea Map[SIZE][SIZE];` in other files from which you access the array.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do:

You could make the Map a global variable by declaring it outside of `main()`, and use `extern` to reach it from within `Pirate::mov`.

You could also create a singleton, but that suffers from some of the same problems as globals.

A better solution is a class that contains the Map and the Pirates. When you construct your Pirates you could have each Pirate a reference to the Map.

Comment: I did that its still says MAP, Place was not declared in this scope

Comment: erkhm... `extern` makes a declaration instead of definition. It only says that somewhere the object is definied. Put `static Sea Map[SIZE][SIZE];` in main.cpp and `extern static Sea Map[SIZE][SIZE];` in the files which uses the array.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I added extern static Sea Map[SIZE][Size];
still it says that MAP was not declared in scope

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus You can't combine extern and static (or at least clang didn't let me).  If you want to make the variable global you'll need to remove the static in both of your code snippets.

Comment: I downvoted you for suggesting Singletons and globals.

Comment: @Puppy is there any other way the member function to access array

Comment: @niCk: yes, there is other way, but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: @PGingerPlusPlus besides singleton,global , If I can't access directly the map array mov() is pretty much useless
so can you tell me please?

Comment: @niCk as Puppy said. Also, I'd wrap the array in the additional class.

Comment: @Puppy Thanks a lot for your answer too, could you elaborate in a comment why only a single global array (not many) is bad for the program?